# Formatting toArray results for $in operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.collection.find({},{_id:1}).toArray
```

returns a list like this:

```
[{"_id":id1},{"_id":id2},{"_id":id3}]
```

what I want is this:

```
[id1,id2,id3]
```

Is this possible? Reason: I'm trying to create an array that is properly formatted for the $in operator.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn [{"_id":id1},{"_id":id2},{"_id":id3}] into [id1,id2,id3]
 with an array method like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? With something like the following:

```
arr.reduce(function(acc, val){
 acc.push(val._id);
 return acc;
}, []);
```

Or try [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/): 
 db.collection.distinct('_id')